# apt-get update error due to armhf

Tags: linux, cuda, ubuntu-12.04

While installing CUDA on Ubuntu, I ran the following command in the terminal:

`sudo sh -c   'echo "foreign-architecture armhf" >> /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch'`

The command failed and when  I do `sudo apt-get update`, it gives me a whole bunch of `failed to fetch`errors. My CUDA installation however, succeeded. How can I revert it back, so that I don't get errors when I update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to delete the entry "foreign-architecture armhf" from "/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch" file.

Answer (score 8):

In my case,

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
```

If you have annoying `dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'armhf' currently in use by the database`, consider remove `armhf` packages which you'll get from `dpkg -l | grep armhf` command

Comment: What if I need tools for arm cross compilation (for Tegra etc) on x86 PC? Will I be able to use this tools if armhf will be removed by this command?

Answer (score 2):

first:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep armhf | awk '{print $1}'`
```

then

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
```